# Fonts used on this site

Tags: discussion, mathjax, design, font

What fonts are used on this site, for text and mathematics.
It looks like Computer Modern, but it seems less "thin" and "spindly" than usual, which I like. Maybe someone fattened up the shapes, or the hinting is very good,
or something ?

There was another question asking the same thing, and the answer was "Georgia", but I don't know if that refers to the text font, the math font, or both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Georgia` is used for the text in posts, but not for all text: for example, "Related" links to the right are in `Helvetica Neue`. The font in the formulas is identified as `MathJax_Math`, which is probably not very helpful to you.

Most modern browsers have a built-in (or easily added) developer tool (usually launched by pressing F12) which allows you to inspect any element of any webpage and learn everything you want about the fonts, images, scripts, etc.

Comment: Just an addition. The math font will depend on the user's system. If the STIX fonts are installed, then MathJax will use those instead of downloading its MathJax webfonts (for better performance).